# how to change "xxx object" in django admin result list

Tags: django-admin

Please take a look at this picture:

[image]

I am trying to change "business object" text to it's instance name. I wonder if there is an easy way to do that without dealing with django's core code.

This is the model I'm using:

```
class Business(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
description = models.TextField(blank=True)
industry = models.ManyToManyField(Industry)


class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Business'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Businesses'

def __unicode__(self):
   return  "%s: %s" % (self.id, self.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the method `__str__` instead of `__unicode__`.  See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api and look for the info box called "`__str__ or __unicode__?`".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here. As Brenda J. Butler indicated (the link), it looks like if you are using Python 3.x you should define **str**() instead of **unicode**.